# How to upload JSON Object to PHP?

Tags: android

I have an activity which contains a Button,Whenever user click on button, we create one JSON object.
I want to post this JSON object in PHP.I search for that,I got so many solution.But i didn't understand what is going there.pls explain and send sample code plz.

pls help thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is hard to understand. Do you want to HTTP POST your object? Are you creating the JSON object in one language and want to read it with PHP?
Have you looked at serialize() or json_encode()?

Comment: thks Mr.Matt,just i create one JSON object, i want post that object to server